# How can I validate OASIS XML files?

Tags: medical, healthcare-finder-api

I need to check OASIS export files.I would like to know if there is an API/service(s) for checking/validating reports in OASIS XML files.

Comment: Can you explain what is in an OASIS file so I can do a halfway decent Google?